# DynamoDB: Query only every 10th value

Tags: javascript, database, nosql, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am querying data between two specific unixtime values. for example:

all data between **1516338730** (today, 6:12) and **1516358930** (today, 11:48)

my database receives a new record every minute. Now, when i want to query the data of last 24h, its way too dense. every 10th minute would be perfect.

my question now is: how can i read **only every 10th database record**, using DynamoDB?

As far as i know, theres no posibility to use modulo or something similar that pleases my needs.

This is my AWS Lambda Code so far:

```
  var read = {
    TableName: "user",
    ProjectionExpression:"#time, #val",
    KeyConditionExpression: "Id = :id and TIME between :time_1 and :time_2",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#time": "TIME",
        "#val": "user_data"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
      ":id": event, // primary key 
      ":time_1": 1516338730,
      ":time_2": 1516358930
    },
    ScanIndexForward: true
  };
  docClient.query(read, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      callback(err, null);
    }
    else {
      callback(null, data.Items);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: What do mean by `only every 10th database record`,  you mean the time period between now (query start time) and 10 minute ago. Or you want query dynamoDb paginated by 10 minutes segments.

Comment: paginated by 10 minute segments between `time_1` and `time_2`.

Comment: You can use moment.js to caculate the time segement. And you need to save you query start time and a count in your client side. page1  query will be `time_1 = now() - (1 - 1) * 10 min; time_2 = time_1 - 10 min`.  and page n: `time_1 = now() - (n - 1) * 10 min; time_2 = time_1 - 10 min`

Comment: not that what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you insert 1 record every minute?

The following might be an option:

At the time of insertion, set another field on the record, let's call it `MinuteBucket`, which is calculated as `the timestamp's minute value mod 10`.

If you do this via a stream function, you can handle new records, and then write something to touch old records to force a calculation.

Your query would change to this:

```
/*...snip...*/
KeyConditionExpression: "Id = :id and TIME between :time_1 and :time_2 and MinuteBucket = :bucket_id",
/*...snip...*/
ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
  ":id": event, // primary key 
  ":time_1": 1516338730,
  ":time_2": 1516358930,
  ":bucket_id": 0 //can be 0-9, if you want the first record to be closer to time_1, then set this to :time_1 minute value mod 10
},
/*...snip...*/
```

Just as a follow-up thought: if you want to speed up your queries, perhaps investigate using the `MinuteBucket` in an index, though that might come at a higher price.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible with dynamoDB API.

There are FilterExpression that contains conditions that DynamoDB applies after the Query operation, but before the data is returned to you.
But AFAIK it isn't possible to use a custom function. And build-in [functions are poor.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions)

As a workaround, you could mark each 10th item on the client side. And then query with checking attribute_exists (or attribute value) to filter them.

BTW, it would be nice to create the index for 'Id' attribute with sort key 'TIME' for improving query performance.